# Reset Azure AD password through Web API instead of Graph API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Changing password Using Graph API isn't possible

```
Unsupported end-user operations
    Any end user resetting their own password by using PowerShell version 1, version 2, or the Microsoft Graph API.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-writeback#unsupported-writeback-operations

Before I read the above, I attempted to change the Password with the code below:

Instantiating GraphServiceClient

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Directory.AccessAsUser.All", "User.Invite.All" };

IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(authority)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in user.Password.ToCharArray())  // you should fetch the password
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke

var tokens = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, user.UserName, securePassword).ExecuteAsync().Result;

graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(x =>
    {
        x.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Bearer", tokens.AccessToken);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));
```

The Change Password Attempt:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    try
    {
        await graphClient.Me
        .ChangePassword(data["currentPassword"].ToString(), data["newPassword"].ToString())
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();
...
}
```

What are the steps (programmatically/Azure Portal) to allow users to Reset Password? Is there a different method to change Passwords without using Graph API?

Comment: I can change the password using graph api.

Comment: Did you report any errors when you used the graph api to change your password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to Configure account permissions for Azure AD Connect

I had to Enable Password Writeback in the Azure AD Connect ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The graph api can definitely reset the password:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "currentPassword": "Test1234!",
  "newPassword": "Test5678!"
}
```

[image]

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var currentPassword = "{currentPassword}";

var newPassword = "{newPassword}";

await graphClient.Me
    .ChangePassword(currentPassword,newPassword)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Comment: The status code of this request is 200, so it passes successfully. The problem is that I can still login with my old password. Using new password returns "One or more errors occurred. (Federated service at autologon.../winauth/trust/2005/… returned error: Authentication Failure )"

Comment: @Tassisto Very strange, I just tested it, and the password was successfully changed. Can you use [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test it?

Comment: Still no updates, the request passes and returns a 200 status code. When logging in I still use the old password.

Comment: Hi @Carl Zhao
Now it says "Code: Request_ResourceNotFound\r\nMessage: Resource 'guid' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.\r\nInner error:\r\n\tAdditionalData:\r\n\tdate: 2021-07-07T11:46:11\r\n\trequest-id: guid\r\n\tclient-request-id: guid\r\nClientRequestId: guid\r\n"

Comment: do you have SSPR enabled and Reset Password enabled in Azure AD Connect? Are you allowing password writebacks to the on-premise?

Comment: I’m attempting to change my password through Postman or Web API using C#. Not in the Graph API Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your password using Graph API. Here are the steps to follow. 1. Register your web application with AD with appropriate permissions (for example, read/write user details). Use MFA 2. Use the graphics API to reset.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword.AD can also use passwordProfile resource type instead.

Comment: Graphics API - you mean Graph API ?